# could this question be edited or we just ignore it

Tags: discussion, editing

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468841/lxde-input-incredily-laggy), no formating mistakes, no misspelling, it's just 2 huge text, I wanted to edit it and separate it into different paragraphs.

Is this edit considered too minimal, or could we do it? just hitting `enter`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a common misconception about "too minor".

If there is something wrong with a post (and no paragraph breaks is wrong!) and you fix it great!

Too minor is only for when you:

- a: only fix some of the problems and leave a bunch (note *a bunch*, if you miss a thing or two that's ok)
- b: It's pointless. Some tiny edits really just don't need to be made.

So in this case, go for it!

<sup>You may hit a roadblock however, because edits require a 6 character change and whitespace doesn't count.</sup>

Comment: I agree. @Fischer if you are worried about your edit being too minor, then probably it is not too minor. Edits that are too minor are mostly edits of people that just change one letter for the fun of it or for the +2 reputation. Adding space to a text is not too minor because it increases the readability.